# SQL Server - Firewall Blocking Replication Even Though Port 1433 is Allowed

Tags: sql-server, windows-firewall, transactional-replication

I have two servers, Server 1 and Server 2, both are stand-alone, Windows Server 2016 with SQL Server 2017 using default instance. They are not members of a domain, and connected over a VPN (using Neorouter).

I am trying to set up replication using a push subscription from Server 1 (local) to Server 2 (remote).

I have created a firewall rule to allow port 1433 through and I have set Server 2 to listen on that port only on the VPN IP address. Server 2 is a default instance so dynamic ports should not be an issue; nevertheless, I have turned on SQL browser and have also allowed port 1434 UDP through the firewall.

I have no problem connecting to Server 2 using SSMS and also when using the create subscription wizard, I can connect to Server 2 to select the target database. When the subscription job runs, however, it fails with a ‘cannot connect to subscriber’ error. I have tried impersonation and using a SQL login, same problem with both.

This seems to be a firewall issue because when I temporarily turn off the firewall on Server 2, the job runs fine.

I can’t see anything in the firewall log to tell me what the problem is, I can see the connection from Server 1 on port 1433 but it just shows action ALLOW and path as RECEIVE.

Any suggestions as to what I need to do on the firewall?

Comment: Have you checked the Windows Firewall log to see which ports have connections blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out eventually - Port 137 UDP has to be enabled on Server 2